# Having a self updating list

Tags: ajax

So i'm looking to use Wordpress as a somewhat dashboard. For this, i want to be able to use AJAX to pull in lists of query data.

However, where it gets complicated i want to be able to have the data be added to, updated, deleted etc and it automatically shows up in the div.

So say if you have a list of items. And somebody ads an item. I want that item to automatically show up on the list, or if someone else has added an item somewhere, it'll then update without a page update.

Hoping someone may have a good place for me to start?

Comment: Could you add a little more detail about what sort of things should trigger updates on this dashboard? Are these items also managed in WordPress?

Comment: In my mind it almost works like a chat board. Where it has a list of posts, and you can add a post, and it'll automatically refresh on everyone in the chat's browser with the new post.